# import TensorFlow error even with Visual Studio installed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I encountered a problem when I import tensorflow. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 already.

The following is the error messages:

> import tensorflow as tf
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\yhlauai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: The error says _The specified module could not be found._ Have you checked that all the files are really in the positions that the error message is giving you?

Comment: This question needs a [mcve] to be answerable.